# How to use loop devices locally in Docker

Tags: docker, device, device-driver

I want to use loop devices in a docker container locally. It means, when running a couple of container all of them should have for instance a /dev/loop0 connected to a file local in the container. I tried

```
[root@600bbfb452d1 /]# mknod /dev/loop20 b 7 20
[root@600bbfb452d1 /]# dd if=/dev/random of=loopfile1 bs=1M count=2
[root@600bbfb452d1 /]# losetup -a | grep 20
/dev/loop20: [0049]:3553002 (/loopfile1)
```

so far so good. But going back to host I can see:

```
[loewe@linux-2 ~]$ losetup -a | grep 20
/dev/loop20: []: (/loopfile1)
```

the loop device /dev/loop20 was also created in the hosts /dev - as my fear was because of the tmpfs mount - and worst the container local file "loopfile1" is attached to hosts loop dev.

I tries to umount the /dev filesystem in the container but didn't succeed (device busy but no proc visible with lsof).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

BTW: using iscsi devices in a container should have the same problem.

Thanks Heiko

Comment: since containers use namespaces, not virtualization, for isolation, they share a kernel.  Any device available to a container is inherently available in the underlying host if not namespace isolated.  I'm skeptical about using loop files being a particularly good idea, but you haven't shared your use case so I can't really recommend an alternative.

Comment: Generally you can't mount(8) at all inside a container.  It's probably _possible_ to work around it, but I'd probably just not use Docker for this case.  You need root-equivalent permissions both to create the loopback device on the host and to run a container.  (Membership in a `docker` group is "root-equivalent" since you can edit any file on the host as root.)